# How can I cancel CGContextClipToRect? (iOS)

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, uiview, uiviewcontroller

I am working with some library. I need to edit some context. And I have a reference to that context.

I find out before I implement my code, in that library called CGContextClipToRect. I need to cancel that clipping. How can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly undo a clipping:

> This function sets the specified graphics context’s clipping region to the area which intersects both the current clipping path and the specified rectangle.

You can only clip to smaller rectangles. Once some area has been removed, you can't get it back.

However, you can save and restore the entire graphics state which includes the clip region. Before clipping, you can call `CGContextSaveGState()` and later call `CGContextRestoreGState()`. This will reset many parameters (see the docs for the full list), but will leave the path (i.e. what has been drawn).